# isolating function from a difficult equation using ln to show it's continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity, logarithms

can you please help me isolate  a function from a difficult equatation?

i need to prove that g(x) is continuous, and to do so, i need to isolate it to prove it using arithmetics of continuous functions.

i have $\left(\frac{\left(1+h\left(x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{h\left(x\right)}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}=exp\left(\frac{h\left(x\right)}{x}g\left(x\right)\right)$

basically, both of them define f(x) so i compared them. h(x) is continuous on I that contains $x=0$, $h(0)=0,h(x)>-1,h(x) \ne 0$ for every $0 \ne x \in I$.

$f(x)=\left(\frac{\left(1+h\left(x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{h\left(x\right)}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is defined for every $0 \ne x \in I$.

i need to show that a continuous function in I, g(x), exists so that $g(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=exp\left(\frac{h\left(x\right)}{x}g\left(x\right)\right)$.

i don't know how to isolate g(x) from the equation, but i supplied all the details from the question. is isolating g(x) is the only way to prove continuity under the given conditions or is there a smarter way? (seems like a mclaurins polynom)?

basically i need help in isolating g(x), but if you think there's a smarter way to show that g(x) is continuous i would like to learn from it.

thank you very much and sorry for not being able to provide additional attemps as i'm stuck on how to get g(x) out of the first equation to prove it's continuous.

Comment: (For $x \ne 0$) take logarithm of both sides, and multiply by $x/h(x)$.  Then worry about what happens as $x \to 0$.

Comment: this is what i already know, what i don't know is how to do it lol

Comment: It simplifies quite a bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at in the comments, take logs.

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{\left(1+h\left(x\right)\right)^{\frac{1}{h\left(x\right)}}}{e}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}&=\exp\left(\frac{h\left(x\right)}{x}g\left(x\right)\right)\\\frac1x\log\left(\frac{(1+h)^{\frac1h}}{e}\right)&=\frac hx g\\\frac1x\frac1h\log(1+h)-\frac1x\log e&=\frac hxg\\\implies g&=\frac1{h^2}(\log(1+h)-h)\end{align}$$
Now take the limit as $x\to 0$
$$g(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\left\{\frac{\log(1+h(x))-h(x)}{h(x)^2}\right\}$$
Then using the fact that $h(0)=0$, 
$$\begin{align}g(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left\{\frac{\log(1+h)-h}{h^2}\right\}\\
\text{(l'hopital)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left\{\frac{\frac1{1+h}-1}{2h}\right\}\\
\text{(re-arrange)}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left\{\frac{-1}{2(1+h)}\right\}\\
&=-\frac12\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you so much! i understand what i did wrong and i'm glad that the way i wated to prove is correct, even though i didn't know how to take log correctly.

thank you so much again!